# wcf - enable windows AND username authentication

Tags: windows, wcf

What are the important configuration points needed to enable a scenario where a WCF service can be called with
either
the logged-on-users windows credentials
or
a username/password combination.

I'm pretty sure I know how to set them up, but what I don't know is how I can force usage of the username/password endpoint.

Is it simply a matter of using the constructor that allows you to specify a particular endpoint, and then setting `ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName` and `.Password` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as your configuration client endpoints exist in config and are configured for the relevent authentication method, you are right, it is as simple as specifying the configuration name in the constructor and supplying the uname/pwd to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to change the binding on the endpoint;

```
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding name="WSHttpUserName">
    <security>
      <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Now if you want automatic windows authentication then you'll need another endpoint, with another binding at the clientCredentialType of "Windows"

Or you can put it in the transport and not the message, but in any case you will need SSL for username authentication.